# Ajax instant insert in database

Tags: php, ajax, database, instant

I'm trying to make an instant insert and instant deletion in my database. (By instant I mean: no reloading. Just the same as a Facebook like button)

So, with some help, I got on this :

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('.bouton').click(function(){
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var id_membre = "<?php $_SESSION['membre'] ?>";
    var lus = "<?php echo $lus; ?>";

    if(lus = 0)
    {        
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "add.php",
        data: {"id_livre": id, "id_membre" : id_membre}
    }
    else {
    $.akax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "delete.php",
        data: {"id_livre": id, "id_membre" : id_membre}
    }
    });
});
});
</script>
```

Clicking on the button, if the user has not read the article (lus = 0), it adds a line in the database, if it has already read (lus = 1) and clicked, it removes the line.

What do you think. I'm sure there is several errors but this is a beginning.

Thank you for your help.
Cordially.

Comment: I don't think akax is going to do much.. But looks fine for the rest..

Comment: This is more suited for codereview.stackexchange.com since you do not really seem to be asking about a specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(lus == 0)

else {
$.ajax({
```

and I will add a success function :

```
success:function(callback){alert("ok");},
```

and an error function :

```
error:function(callback){alert(callback)}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add in some response and error checking.. split up the two commands:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "add.php",
    data: {"id_livre": id, "id_membre" : id_membre}
}).done( function( response )
{
    // deal with response code - success / fail message?
}).fail( function()
{
    alert( "something broke" );
});
```

.. and repeat for the other one..